# Facebook Ads API Cookie Matching for non RTB

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, cookie-matching

I know that the rtb works with the 302 redirect, in my script tag, and that is working, but can i use the cookie matching in the normal ads or only in the RTB (FBX) Ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie matching from the RTB protocol is only used for RTB ads, not for other targeting options or use with other Ads APIs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/rtb/

Comment: But @Igy if i a customer buy a daily banner (like the logout banner), i cant check cookies or try to use any retargeting technique ?

Comment: The cookie matching you're referring to is for use with RTB ads to help Facebook identify which users you want to reach with the realtime bidded ads - there are other targeting options available for other cases

Comment: So @Igy, we are and AdServer that works with retargeting and dynamic created images in real time, so if i have a normal ad like a daily ad, and i wan't to recognise if the customer that is seeing that banner has passed on my site so i can dynamically change the banner for him, is that possible?

Comment: Sorry for keeping bothering you all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question - are you asking if there are other realtime options for modifying the creative based on cookie matching of the viewing user other than by using FBX? If so, i don't believe so